# Bootstrap container leans a little left when it should be centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I am having trouble aligning the content of the website because it always wants to go a little to the left.  This predicament stands out the best in the mobile view.

http://becyclefit.com

As you can see the content (container) is a little left from the center.  I have no idea if this is coming from Bootstrap, my CSS, or the HTML itself.  I have messed with the floats in my CSS and I managed to shift it, but instead it moved to the right! I would like to center this.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
 max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
 width:100%;
}
body {
    background-color: white; 
 margin-top: 30px;
}
hr {
  border: 0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;               
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  height: 3px;
}
a.footerText:hover {
 color: #999;
}
a.socialIcons {
    margin: 10px;
    opacity: .6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

a.socialIcons:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}



/*
 Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
 ----------------------------------
 dw-num-cols-mobile:  5;
 dw-num-cols-tablet:  8;
 dw-num-cols-desktop: 10;
 dw-gutter-percentage: 10;
 
 Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
 http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design
 
 and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
 http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: auto;
 /* padding-left: 0.8272%;
 padding-right: 0.8272%; */
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#bikes {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
    padding: 10% 0;
}
#trips {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
    padding: 10% 0;
}
#seminars {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
    padding: 10% 0;
}
#faq {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: left;
    padding: 10% 0;
}
#footer {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
    text-align: center;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.footerText {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-top: 3%;
 padding-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
}
a.footeraltText:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.yungText {
 color: #7d7d7d;
 font-size: .9em;
 margin: 3% 2%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.crossOut {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
.socialIconGroup {
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.navbar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
.bikeCatalog {
    padding: 10% 0;
}
.catalogItem {
    text-align: center;
}
.catalogItem img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.nav-divider {
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}
.carouselImage {
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
#cycleLogo {
 height: 50px;
}
 
}
/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
 width: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#header {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#navbar {
    float: right;
}
#bikes {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#trips {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#seminars {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#faq {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#footer {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}




@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#header {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#navbar {
 float: right;
}
#bikes {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}
#trips {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
} 
#seminars {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#faq {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#footer {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class=""> 
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    <meta name="author" content="Gabe Petersen, Reagan Jones, Cycle Fitness, FBLA">
    <meta name="description" content="Website for Cycle Fitness, a new company opening up in New York City. Our shop’s address is 123 Avenue of the Americas, New York, NY 20013. Our welcoming store sells a variety of bicycles, including road bikes, mountain bikes, cyclocross bikes, folding bikes, electric-assist bikes, women’s bikes, children bikes, etc. The owner also plans to have seminars on bike safety, cycling for fitness, choosing the right bike, etc., as well as have monthly cycle trips in and out of the city. We are happy to answer any questions about your bikes as well as ours. ">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    
<title>Cycle Fitness</title>
 
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/dm01umt3yoin2uz/bootstrap.css?dl=0" rel="stylesheet">
    
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/o8oorcl1tdp2r5w/bootstrap.min.css?dl=0" rel="stylesheet">
    
<link href="css/fluid_index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7i775ga1haacy5d/fluid_index.css?dl=0" rel="stylesheet">
    
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cycle Fitness</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/fgr66qrbrnzdnbr/bikes.html?dl=0">Bikes</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d5skwprpwa0n6yy/trips.html?dl=0">Trips</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qy3ihosg3vwq2xb/seminars.html?dl=0">Seminars</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/1klmf3mwremeuac/faq.html?dl=0">Q &amp; A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    
  <div class="header"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/cow71e5bfnnjo31/homeheader.jpg?dl=0" name="imagewrapper" class="imagewrapper"/></div>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="bikes" class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/o7o73pyqi5k27qm/thumbtree.jpg?dl=0" class="img-rounded" alt="Bikes"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="lead">Bikes</p>
                <p class="yungText"> In the shop, you will notice that we carry a wide variety of bikes that are quality selected to fit each of our customers needs. Whether you are just starting out or you ride professionally, our staff will always be able to help.</p>
                  <a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/fgr66qrbrnzdnbr/bikes.html?dl=0">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg footerText">
        Catalog
     </button>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
      
  <div id="trips" class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/rai794ad7fyew0t/thumbsunset.jpg?dl=0" class="img-rounded" alt="Trips"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="lead">Trips</p>
                <p class="yungText">Here at Cycle Fitness, we are not limited to selling bikes, but we also get communities involved: by having trips in and out of Manhattan. We expose many cyclists to different enviroments, while keeping safety top priority.</p>
                <a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d5skwprpwa0n6yy/trips.html?dl=0">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg footerText">
                    Schedule
                  </button>
                </a>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="seminars" class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/a2v5b8cp8ll5wpw/thumbclouds.jpg?dl=0" alt="Seminars" class="img-rounded"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="lead">Seminars</p>
                <p class="yungText">Along with getting the community active with cycling trips, we also offer free seminars on preparation for many different aspects of cycling.</p>
                <a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qy3ihosg3vwq2xb/seminars.html?dl=0">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg footerText">
                    Dates
                  </button>
                </a>                
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
      
  <div id="faq" class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-6">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/djn5c6i1r20jdzs/thumbbeach.jpg?dl=0" class="img-rounded" alt="Q &amp; A"></div>
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                <p class="lead">Q &amp; A</p>
                <p class="yungText">All of your questions are considered with great respect, and we reply to all of them.  If they are asked frequently, they are put on our Q &amp; A for your convienence.</p>
                <a href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/1klmf3mwremeuac/faq.html?dl=0">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg footerText">
                    Go to
                  </button>
                </a>                
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-3"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
<!-- end container-fluid -->
</div> 
  
  <div id="footer" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 socialIconGroup">
        <a class="socialIcons" href="https://www.facebook.com/becyclefit" title="like us on facebook" alt="facebook icon"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/pbyk2eho1lqrmzq/Social%20icons%20by%20Dreamstale%20%286%29.png?dl=0"></a>  
        <a class="socialIcons" href="https://twitter.com/becyclefit" title="follow us on twitter" alt="twitter icon"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/y1gbz3rkcnj4ndn/Social%20icons%20by%20Dreamstale%20%283%29.png?dl=0"></a>
        <a class="socialIcons" href="https://plus.google.com/117298972535280093370/about" title="follow us on google+" alt="google plus icon"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/gfclggry33ya2qr/Social%20icons%20by%20Dreamstale%20%2827%29.png?dl=0"></a>
        <a class="socialIcons" href="http://becyclefit.tumblr.com/" title="follow us on tumblr" alt="tumblr icon"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/d9bogu5ez71nbbb/Social%20icons%20by%20Dreamstale%20%2813%29.png?dl=0"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
     <p><a class="footerText" href="#footer">9am - 5pm &nbsp; | &nbsp; Mon - Sat</a></p>
     <p><a class="footerText" href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/123+Avenue+of+the+Americas,+New+York,+NY+10013/@40.7239272,-74.0046749,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c2598c9bd1a0e5:0x80cfad7a5ba7a114">123 Avenue of the Americas, New York</a></p>
     <p><a class="footerText" href="mailto:becyclefit@gmail.com">becyclefit@gmail.com</a></p>
     <p><a class="footerText" href="tel://(555) 555-5555">(555) 555-5555</a></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 footerText"><p>&copy; Gabe A. Petersen 2015</p></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
        
   <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6zgznegu8x995bs/bootstrap.min.js?dl=0"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the custom `width: 100%;` you kept from all your row ids (e.g. #bike).

Also, remove the `float` and `display:block` too as that is not required (All divs are set to block by default).

--UPDATE--
** Wrap your footer div within a container-fluid class and remove the 100% width from that row too.

----Why are almost all your elements being specified a 100% width btw?? The container and container-fluid has default width values which I wouldn't recommend overriding them unless you really need to.----

Comment: Thank You so much.  Previously, I was using the Adobe Dreamweaver responsive design until I realized that it was absolutely frail to Bootstrap's , lol.  So, I had some code lingering from the dreamweaver fluid_index.css, and I wasn't sure what to delete or where to look cause I'm a beginner to web design.  I guess I was just confused but thank you very much again.